# additional space or box generated automatically in IE

Tags: html, jsp, fieldset

In my page, an additional space or box is generated automatically in IE...But it is working fine in other browsers...I dont know what is the reason for this...I have attached the screenshot...
In the screenshot, you can find a small space or box...That is the one which is generated automatically...
[image]

My code :

```
<s:form name="CompanyInformationForm" action="CompanyInformation"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <span class="headerLabelText"> <s:text  name="companyInformation"></s:text>
    </span>
    <br/><br/>
    <table summary="header data for Company Information text table">
      <caption class="captionHide">Company Information</caption>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" align="left" headers="companyinfoheader1"><span class="paragraphText">
        <s:property value="%{companyinfoheader1}"/></span></th>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td headers="companyinfoheader2"><span class="paragraphText">
        <s:property value="%{companyinfoheader2}"/></span></td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
    <fieldset style="display:block;">
        <table class="mi360Field" width="100%" summary="Upload Issuer File table">
        <caption class="captionHide">Upload Issuer</caption>
        <tr>
        <th scope="row" align="left" width="50%" headers="uploadIssuerTemplate">
            <span>
                 <span class="purpleHeaderText"> <s:text name="uploadIssuerTemplate"></s:text></span>
            </span><br/><br/>
            <table summary="provider directory file upload table">
             <caption class="captionHide">Upload File</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td headers="issuerFileType">
                     <span class="headerLabelText"> <s:property value="%{issuerFileType}"/> : </span></td>

                    <td headers="fileTypeID"><s:select cssClass="selectBox" name="documentUtilDTO.fileTypeID" title="issuer file type" list="fileType"  listKey="key" listValue="value"
                    titleKey="fileType" label="%{issuerFileType}" title="fileType"

                    style="width:225px" styleId="newPageMessageType">
                    </s:select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><th scope="row" align="left"></th></tr>
                <tr><td headers="uploadissuerFile">
                      <span class="headerLabelText"> <s:text name="uploadissuerFile"></s:text>
                    </span></td>
                    <td headers="fileData"><div class="fileinputs"><s:file name="documentUtilDTO.fileData" label="test" title="test" tooltipIconPath="../../KY/images/common/buttons/uploadBtn.png" title = "Browse" tooltip="Browse..." size="20" cssClass="file" /></div></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:a href="#" accesskey="u" onclick="submitForm('UploadCompanyInformation')"><img id="uploadBtn" src="../../KY/images/common/buttons/uploadBtn.png" alt="upload" style="border: none;"  /></s:a></td>
                </tr>           
            </table>

        </th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br></br>

        <div id="divDocuments" style="height:auto;overflow-y:auto;border: none;">
            <br />
            <s:form>
            <s:url id="downloadCompanyinfoDOC" action="downloadCompanyinfoDOC" > </s:url>
            <display:table  export="false" id="data"  class="displayTableBorder"  style="width:70%;" name="listCmpInfDto" uid="fileDetails"  rules="rows"  requestURI="CompanyInformation" pagesize="3" summary="Company Information list">
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.onepage" value="" />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.no_items_found" value="" />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.one_item_found" value="" />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.all_items_found" value="" />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.some_items_found" value="" />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.page.separator" value=" " />
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="5" />
                <display:caption media="html" class="captionHide">document List</display:caption>
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<p><span id="hix-pagination"><span> <a id="doublePrevCompany" class="prev" href="{1}">&#9668;&#9668;</a> <a id="singlePrevCompany" class="prev" href="{2}">&#9668;</a> {0} <a id="singleNextCompany" class="next" href="{3}">&#9658;</a> <a id="doubleNextCompany" class="next" href="{4}">&#9658;&#9658; </a></span></span></p>' /> 
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<p><span id="hix-pagination"><span> <a id="doublePrevCompany" class="prev" href="{1}">&#9668;&#9668;</a> <a id="singlePrevCompany" class="prev" href="{2}">&#9668;</a> {0} <a id="singleNextCompany" class="next" href="{3}">&#9658;</a> <a id="doubleNextCompany" class="next" href="{4}">&#9658;&#9658; </a></span></span></p>' /> 
                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<p><span id="hix-pagination"><span> <a id="doublePrevCompany" class="prev" href="{1}">&#9668;&#9668;</a> <a id="singlePrevCompany" class="prev" href="{2}">&#9668;</a> {0} <a id="singleNextCompany" class="next" href="{3}">&#9658;</a> <a id="doubleNextCompany" class="next" href="{4}">&#9658;&#9658; </a></span></span></p>' />                                                                                                      

                <display:column property="fileType" scope="colgroup" title="${documentFileType}"     sortable="true" headerClass="hixTableHeader"  class="displayTagtd" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;"  media="html" />
                <display:column property="fileName" scope="colgroup" url="${downloadCompanyinfoDOC}" sortable="true" paramProperty="companyDocID" paramId="documentUtilDTO.documentId" title="${documentFileName}"   headerClass="hixTableHeader"   class="displayTagtd" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;"/>
                <display:column property="creationDate" scope="colgroup"  title="${uploadDate}"  sortable="true"   headerClass="hixTableHeader"  class="displayTagtd" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;"  />
                <display:column property="createdBy" scope="colgroup" title="${uploadBy}" sortable="true"  headerClass="hixTableHeader"  class="displayTagtd" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;"  />
            </display:table>
            <br></br>
            <table style="width:70%; overflow-y:auto;border: none;" summary="button section">
            <caption class="captionHide" >button section</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" width=50% align="left"><s:a href="#" accesskey="c" onclick="submitForm('IssuerHome')"><img id="cancelBtn" src="../../KY/images/common/buttons/closeBtn.png" alt="close" style="border: none;" /></s:a></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            </s:form>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <span style="display:none"><s:submit/></span>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't see where the box/space is. Please can you be a bit more specific.

Comment: hi,I have edited the image....R u able to see now

Comment: In IE, hit F12 to get the developer tools up. There is a button towards the top left that looks like a box with an arrow which will allow you to select the element and inspect the HTML and styling. See if you can spot the problem there.

Comment: Actually, I tried that...But it is not able to select the element....In my code,there is a line <fieldset style="display:block">...If I give <fieldset style="position:absolute">, I am not getting that extra box...But if I specify position as absolute,the width of the fieldset is reduced...And if I specify width through style attribute,again I am getting this box....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three < br / > after the last table may be the cause of this if your fieldset is set to block.

Also as a side issue, you have nested forms which is not really allowed in HTML prior to v5. IE will probably have trouble trying to render these properly.

### Update

As per the comments , the issue was nested forms

Comment: Even after removing the <br/>, I am getting the box

Comment: Got it...The problem is because of nested forms...Thanks